# Integrate Apollo subscriptions on iOS with Action Cable being used on the backend for websockets

Tags: swift, websocket, apollo, actioncable, starscream

I'm trying to make [Apollo subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720378/how-to-implement-graphql-subscription-using-apollo-ios-client) on iOS work with a backend that is using Action Cable to implement websockets. I learned that the iOS app needs to send `command`, `channel` and `channel id` to the backend to make subscriptions work ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145429/connecting-to-actioncable-from-ios-app)). I have tried to use the function write `func write(_ str: String, force forced: Bool = false, id: Int? = nil)` in `WebSocketTransport.swift` on WebSocketTransport object when initializing instance of Apollo. Below you can see how I'm doing that.

```
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        var authPayloads = Dictionary<String, String> ()
        var authToken = ""
        if let token = userDefault.object(forKey: "token") {
            authToken = "\(token)"
            authPayloads.updateValue(authToken, forKey: "authorization")
        }
       let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
       configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = authPayloads

        let map: GraphQLMap = authPayloads
        let wsEndpointURL = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/subscriptions/\(authToken)")!
        let endpointURL = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api")!

        websocket = WebSocketTransport(request: URLRequest(url: wsEndpointURL), connectingPayload: map)
       var channelId = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000))
       websocket?.write(stringify(json: ["command":"subscribe", "identifier": stringify(json: ["channel":"channelName", "channelId": channelId])]))

        let splitNetworkTransport = SplitNetworkTransport(
            httpNetworkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(
                url: endpointURL,
                configuration: configuration
            ),
            webSocketNetworkTransport: websocket!
        )
        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: splitNetworkTransport)
    }()
```

However, the backend isn't seeing what I'm writing to the WebSocket Transport object in their logs and I'm not able to subscribe to that specific channel. Any idea how I can make use Apollo subscriptions on iOS if the backend is using Action Cable, and make the two work together?

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution** for now is to use **[Swift-ActionCableClient](https://github.com/Kaakati/Swift-ActionCableClient/blob/master/README.md)** to recieve streams, and use the mutations/queries from **ApolloClient**.

**Unfortenatly!** **Apollo iOS** doesn't know how to communicate with ActionCable channels, this issue is reported on Apollo-iOS [Github Issue #634](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/634) & Your issue [Github Issue #454](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/454)