# Subscription Failure Error WSError(type: Starscream.ErrorType.upgradeError message: \"Invalid HTTP upgrade\", code: 400)?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo-server, apollo-ios

I need to integrate `subscription` in my iOS  app. The `subscription` works fine on `localhost` in `graphiql`. I have deployed my backend on `Heroku`. I am using `apollo-server` and not `hasura`. My `subscriptions` are not working for the url given by Heroku but it works fine on `localhost`. `Queries` and `mutations` work fine for both `localhost` and `Heroku` url. So I am trying to access my `subscription` from my iOS  client. I have kept the base url as my local host. The queries and mutations part works for my iOS client but my `subscription` part is not working.

I have configured my Apollo client for subscription by adding this

```
let httpNetworkTransport = HTTPNetworkTransport(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:5000")!)
        httpNetworkTransport.delegate = self

        let webSocketTransport = WebSocketTransport(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:5000")!))


         let splitNetworkTransport = SplitNetworkTransport(
          httpNetworkTransport: httpNetworkTransport,
          webSocketNetworkTransport: webSocketTransport
        )

        return ApolloClient(networkTransport: splitNetworkTransport)
```

I also tried replacing `http` with `ws` as follows

```
let webSocketTransport = WebSocketTransport(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:5000")!))
```

Subscription code is as follows

```
subscription = Network.shared.apollo.subscribe(subscription: GetHealthConsultationSubscriptionSubscription()){
            [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            switch result {
            case .success(let result):
                debugPrint(result.data?.healthConsultation.chiefComplaint)

            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint(" Subscription Failure Error \(error)")
            }
        }
```

But I am getting error from my iOS client as follows

```
" Subscription Failure Error WSError(type: Starscream.ErrorType.upgradeError, message: \"Invalid HTTP upgrade\", code: 400)"
```

Also when I use `Graphiql` for my subscription and replace `localhost` with the `Heroku` url for my subscription , I get following error.

[image: s]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376836/6124657 ?

Comment: @xadm I don't have any headers for my api

Comment: maybe you should have? is this stopping you with testing this working solution?

Comment: @xadm yes otherwise my code is same to the answer you mentioned. I don't have any API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was no problem from my `ios Code`. The issue was with the free tier of `Heroku` I am using. I tried replacing my `subscription` with `Hasura's Subscription` `https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/ios/subscriptions/1-subscription/` and it works.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us informed

Comment: Hi, could you tell me more info on why heroku free tier throws this error?